# Displaying broken image in HTML

Tags: html

I have made a div as follows:

```
<div class="fbook" style=" border:thin; border:1px solid black; float: right; margin-top:50px; margin-right:5px">
                <img src="facebook.jpg"></img>
</div>
```

The facebook.jpg file is placed in the same folder as that of the html file. But still the image appears to be broken in the browser. I guess the browser cannot locate the image path. Can anyone please help me resolve this issue. The image is as follows:

[image]

Comment: It should work. Check whether you have image and extension properly. Try to use debugger tools like firebug for firefox and developer tools in case of chrome to check errors.

Comment: Are you sure the image itself is not broken? Can you upload it so we can test it out?,

Comment: @KeluThatsall I have added the image for your reference.

Comment: @Unknown You were right the image extension was wrong. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image is a self closing tag:

```
<img src="facebook.jpg" />
```

Double check that you spelled it correctly (and used correct capitalization, the file type is `.jpg` and not `.png` or `.gif` etc.). Another thing you could try to do is use the full url:

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/facebook.jpg" />
```

And just some other comments...
You are missing a semi-colon after `margin-right:5px` and you can condense `margin-top` and `margin-right` into shorthand

```
margin:50px 5px 0 0;
```

or

```
margin:50px 5px;
```

if you want the `50px` margin on both top and bottom, and you want the `5px` margin on both left and right.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
<div class="fbook" style="border:1px solid black; float: right; margin-top:50px; margin-right:5px">
<img src="./facebook.jpg" />
</div>
```

I changed the path to `"./"` which means it's relative to where to document is and I also made the `img` tag self-closing. It doesn't have an end tag like a `div` does.

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly ok. I tried putting an image instead of facebook.jpg.

So the question comes ... why are u getting the broken image?

** Please stop using the closing tag  its not required.

Probable Answers:

1. Either the path to the image is wrong, but you mentioned the image is present in the same folder, so this can't be the case.
2. It seems you have deployed your website on a server, and accordingly you have uploaded the image to their server. I had the same problem few years back.What you can try is:

i) I tried using file manager. You must be having two file managers in the control panel,
try using the other one, as it seems the image is getting corrupted during upload.

ii) Check in the file manager whether the image uploaded is fine on the server, its not broken.

iii) Else create a proper images named folder and place the image inside it and give the appropriate path.

Any of this would definitely solve your problem.

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

i check it but all things are correct, img tag doesn't need close tag you can use this form:

and you can use width and height for image tag.